# Problema con consulta SQL y Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo la siguiente consulta que hago en SQL Server

```
select distinct f200_razon_social, f200_nit, f253_id AS Numero_auxiliar, 
f253_descripcion AS Auxiliar,
SUM(f353_total_db - f353_total_cr) as TOTAL
from t350_co_docto_contable
INNER JOIN t200_mm_terceros ON 
t200_mm_terceros.f200_rowid=t350_co_docto_contable.f350_rowid_tercero
INNER JOIN t353_co_saldo_abierto ON 
t353_co_saldo_abierto.f353_rowid_docto=t350_co_docto_contable.f350_rowid
INNER JOIN t253_co_auxiliares ON 
t253_co_auxiliares.f253_rowid=t353_co_saldo_abierto.f353_rowid_auxiliar
INNER JOIN t354_co_mov_saldo_abierto ON 
t354_co_mov_saldo_abierto.f354_rowid_docto=
t350_co_docto_contable.f350_rowid
WHERE f350_id_tipo_docto LIKE 'FV%' AND f200_nit = '1035877400' AND 
f350_id_periodo >= '201807'AND f353_total_db - f353_total_cr <> 0 
AND f253_id = '13050502'
GROUP BY f200_razon_social, f200_nit, f253_id, f253_descripcion
```

Me trae los siguientes resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí mi consulta va bien, ahora explico algo:
El campo `TOTAL` que se muestra es la suma de un campo llamado `f353_total_db` menos otro campo llamado `f353_total_cr` como se ve en el script de SQL.

Estos valores tienen una fecha de vencimiento que se aprecia en un campo llamado `f353_fecha_vcto`,
si resto la `fecha de vencimiento` menos la `fecha actual` me dará un valor al que le llamo `días vencidos`, si los `días vencidos` son igual o menor de 0 me sumara los valores que tengan `días vencidos` igual o menor a cero en un campo llamado `Corriente`, de lo contrario me los sumara en un campo llamado `Vencidos`

Y lo hice modificando mi script SQL y quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
select distinct f200_razon_social, f200_nit, f253_id AS Numero_auxiliar, 
f253_descripcion AS Auxiliar,
SUM(f353_total_db - f353_total_cr) as TOTAL,
case when DATEDIFF(day, f353_fecha_vcto, GETDATE()) > 0 then sum(distinct 
f353_total_db - f353_total_cr) else 0 end 'Vencidos',
case when DATEDIFF(day, f353_fecha_vcto, GETDATE()) <= 0 then 
sum(distinct f353_total_db - f353_total_cr) else 0 end 'Corriente'
from t350_co_docto_contable
INNER JOIN t200_mm_terceros ON 
t200_mm_terceros.f200_rowid=t350_co_docto_contable.f350_rowid_tercero
INNER JOIN t353_co_saldo_abierto ON 
t353_co_saldo_abierto.f353_rowid_docto=t350_co_docto_contable.f350_rowid
INNER JOIN t253_co_auxiliares ON 
t253_co_auxiliares.f253_rowid=t353_co_saldo_abierto.f353_rowid_auxiliar
INNER JOIN t354_co_mov_saldo_abierto ON 
t354_co_mov_saldo_abierto.f354_rowid_docto=
t350_co_docto_contable.f350_rowid
WHERE f350_id_tipo_docto LIKE 'FV%' AND f200_nit = '1035877400' AND 
f350_id_periodo >= '201807'AND f353_total_db - f353_total_cr <> 0 
AND f253_id = '13050502'
GROUP BY f200_razon_social, f200_nit, f253_id, f253_descripcion
```

Agregue dos `CASE` Este script me lanza el siguiente error

> Mens. 8120, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 3
>
> La columna 't353_co_saldo_abierto.f353_fecha_vcto' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.

Cuando agrego el campo `f353_fecha_vcto` al `GROUP BY` me lanza los siguientes resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cual es el problema?
Si se fijan en mi script inicial cuando solo sumaba un `TOTAL` solo me lanzaba un registro, pero ahora cuando adjunto el campo `f353_fecha_vcto` al `GROUP BY` me trae varios registros porque cada valor tiene diferente `Fecha de vencimiento`.

Necesito excluir `f353_fecha_vcto` del `GROUP BY` para que solo me traiga un registro y no varios sin modificar mis `CASE`.

Comment: Solo si es posible, ¿puedes usar [http://sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) o un programa similar y/o puedes [edit] la pregunta para agregar datos de prueba, creando así un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Disculpa no se de que trata ese programa menos usarlo

Comment: Puedes usar SQLFiddle.com para colocar allí la estructura de la tabla y ejemplos de datos. Puedes pulsar allí el botón "View Sample Fiddle" para que veas un ejemplo de estructura allí. Si de pronto no puedes o sigues in tener claro cómo funciona sqfiddle, puedes [edit] la pregunta para agregar la estructura de las tablas y ejemplos de datos en cada tabla que uses en esta consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te da una pista, la columna `f353_fecha_vcto` debiera estar definido en el `GROUP BY` o dentro de alguna de las funciones de agregación, por ejemplo dentro del `SUM()`. Entiendo que en tu caso, debiera estar dentro del `SUM` es decir algo así

```
SUM(case when DATEDIFF(day, f353_fecha_vcto, GETDATE()) > 0 then distinct f353_total_db - f353_total_cr else 0 end) 'Vencidos',
```

Revisa la lógica del otro `CASE` debiera ser similar a lo comentado, también el uso de los `DISTINCT` dentro del `SUM`, no entiendo el sentido.

Comment: El uso del distinct es porque tengo un mismo valor repetido varias veces y cuando voy a hacer la sumatoria me suma los repetidos

Comment: @The_pacha, el tema es que eso te puede traer un grave inconveniente, si realmente tienes dos valores idénticos válidos correspondiente a dos filas distintas, uno de ellos no lo estarías sumando

Comment: Es verdad y no lo había pensado, ahora no se como resolverlo tendré que pensar en algo

Comment: No puedo ayudarte mucho en ese sentido por que desconozco muchas cosas, lo que sí puedo sugerirte es que resuelvas esa sumatoria en una subconsulta aparte solo de la tabla `t353_co_saldo_abierto` con un group by y luego la incorpores a tu consulta principal

Comment: Pues mi amigo, acabo de probar tu código, quitando el distinct de las sumas y funciona a la perfección, te agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0):

Con la información que das lo que puedo decir es que hagas un subquery y ahí meter tu CASE, de esta manera excluyes la declaración en GROUP BY de `f353_fecha_vcto`, solo regresas el resultado que te de ese subquery.

Este es un ejemplo de subquery en T-SQL:

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM Estados WHERE idEstado = Municipios.idEstado) AS Estado FROM Municipios
```

Aquí lo que sucede es que comparas el id del estado de la tabla Municipios en el subquery, es el por qué pongo primero la tabla y luego su columna. `idEstado = Municipios.idEstado`

Comment: Me podes ayudar con un ejemplo? o una manera de implementar un subquery a mi código? no se usar subquerys

Comment: Este es un ejemplo de subquery en T-SQL.

`SELECT (SELECT * FROM Estados WHERE idEstado = Municipios.idEstado) AS Estado FROM Municipios`

Aquí lo que sucede es que comparas el id del estado de la tabla Municipios en el subquery, es el por qué pongo primero la tabla y luego su columna.

` idEstado = Municipios.idEstado`

Espero te sirva el ejemplo.

Comment: @Hadad tu puedes [edit] tu respuesta y colocar esta información en tu respuesta. Saludos.